# QTP, QC, Load Runner and RFT tutorials

Tags: testing, qtp, hp-quality-center, rft

I am newbie in testing. Can you please suggest me some good tutorials of

1. Quality Center
2. Quick Test Professional
3. RFT

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some links to start with.

VBScript: http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/quickref/vbscript_list.html
QTP and VBScript tutorials: http://www.advancedqtp.com/first-steps/tutorials/vbscript-techniques-id124/vbscript-tutorial/
QTP tutorial: http://www.advancedqtp.com/knowledge-base/scripting-qtp/

Answer (score 0):

For Quality Center, just read the documentation provided (see under help menu) it's a bit long, but pretty good, and covers the entire product and work methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to IBM RFT Release notes for Tutorials on RFT.